# Change KEyBoard Layout via flash ( web )?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash

Is it possible to activate alt+shift ( change language) Via JS and some Flash

like copy to clipboard plugin etc. ( via flash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only the user can change the active keyboard layout.